# How do I get an actual word Iterator wrapping breakIterator?

Tags: java, parsing, text, standard-library

I'm using `java.text.breakIterator` for iterating words (which is not an iterator, yes I've noticed, no need to tell me that). Why can't I *get* it as an actual iterator? i.e. why can't I do:

```
Iterator<String> iter = BreakIteratorMagicWrapper.getWordIterator(sourceString);
while(iter.hasNext()) {
    System.out.println("got word %s", iter.next());
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> Why can't I get it as an actual iterator?

Because [`BreakIterator` implements neither `Iterator<Foo>` nor `Iterable<Foo>`.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/BreakIterator.html)

There's nothing stopping you from writing your own `Iterator` or `Iterable` implementation backed by a `BreakIterator`, however. It's just not part of the standard library, for better or for worse.